# Install Mac OS X Server from Apple's website

Tags: mac, installation, dmg-image

I just downloaded Mac OS X Server from Apple's developer website and have the DMG file in my downloads folder. I opened it, let the box pop up, and then it says that I need to restart my computer. I did this, and nothing happens when it starts back up. How do I install this? Do I need to burn it to a disk? If so, how should I do this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question.  But yes, you should put that on a disk (dmg is a disk image).  Use your macs disk utility to burn it.  You're basically opening up a disk by mounting (opening) that dmg file.  It's as though you put in a dvd.  When you reboot your machine from that option it has no dvd in the drive and boots normally.  If you had it on a disk you could hold the c key and boot from the disk to install.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, didn't realize that this was for programming specifically, but I appreciate your help anyway!